apache2.4 + rsyslog sending logs to the remote server + unnecessary systemd logging
I have a following configuration in my Apache2.4 environment (Debian OS):
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t S06_access_log -p local6.info" combined
ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t S06_error_log -p local6.info"

In /etc/rsyslog.conf I'm sending those local6 logs to the remote server:
local6.info @MY_REMOTE_SERVER:514

And this is fine - it works. However those apache logs appear also in the systemd journal - which is unwanted.  So when I run journalctl -f I can see all the apache requests and those requests are logged to the systemd journal.
How can I disable logging local6.info events by systemd ?
I have already tried putting
[Service]
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null

in apache2.service , but it didn't help.

Welcome to [so], a forum for programming questions, Since your questions seems to be unrelated to programming as such, you'll probably have more luck asking on [sf] or Unix & Linux

I managed to do it  quite easily:
instead of sending logs to the local syslogd, I'm sending them directly to remote server (using logger).
As simple as that:
I changed that line
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t S06_access_log -p local6.info" combined
to:
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -n $REMOTE_SERVER_IP -t S06_access_log -p local6.info" combined
maybe it'll be useful to someone
